# AngularJS loading message/please wait

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-service

How can I achieve the following in AngularJS:

[image]

If I have my page that will show some widgets and each widget has a button called refresh. When the button is clicked then the content of that widget is reloaded from server. While the content is reloaded I want to show the user a message within that widget, please wait ... with a possible fading effect.

How can I achieve that in AngularJS?

I kind of taught about having a common service for that purpose and then somehow each widget controller will use that service or something like that, maybe also a directive that will show the actual loading/please wait message?

What is your advise?

P.S. There should be also a loading/please wait message with fading for the whole page, when the route is changing ... like switching between pages.

Comment: fairly easy to acheive using `ng-show` or `ng-class` and a boolean variable scoped per widget such as in a directive

Answer (score 4):

In my recent project I'm using https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy

Very nice thing, all you have to do is put your promise into $scope, and then add cg-busy attr to your element which should have spinner (beside registering module obviously):

Controller:

```
$scope.myPromise = restangular.get('something',12).then(function(response) { ... })
```

Html:

```
<div cg-busy="myPromise"></div>
```

You can also customize template that's gonna be displayed (which includes spinner and text message).

Answer (score 2):

there are implementations of this available on github :  [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) or [angular-sham-spinner](https://github.com/harinair/angular-sham-spinner). Read this [BLOG](http://lemoncode.net/2013/07/31/angularjs-found-great-solution-to-display-ajax-spinner-loading-widget/) which details how the spinner works with angularjs

if you want to implement it yourself to be reusable...

```
app.directive("spinner", function(){
    return: {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { enable: "=" },
        template: '<div class="spinner" ng-show="enable"><img src="content/spinner.gif"></div>'
    }
});
```

i havent tested the code but directive wont be more complex than above...

Answer (score 1):

As harish point out the right way would be a directive, but theres no need if you want of include another dependency, you could do something like this

1. You can create a nice CSS3 only loading (so not images required) animation with the help of [CssLoad](http://cssload.net/)
2. Create a directive with a linking function so you can call and stop the animations within your controller the angular way:

   ```
   .directive('appLoading', function(){
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           templateUrl: 'template-file.html', // or template: 'template html code inline' Display none to the code is important so is not visible if youre not caling the methods
           replace: true,
           link: function(scope, elem) {
               scope.$on('app-start-loading', function(){
                   elem.fadeIn(); //asumming you have jquery otherwise play with toggleClass and visible and invisible classes
               });
               scope.$on('app-finish-loading', function(){
                   elem.fadeOut();
               });
           }
        }
    })
   ```
3. Include in your html code the directive: `<app-loading></app-loading>`
4. Now all you need to do is call the scope methods in your controller like this:

   $scope.$broadcast('app-start-loading'); // to start the loading animation

   $scope.$broadcast('app-finish-loading'); // to stop the animation

NOTE: if all your widgets share a scope, the loading may be triggered in all of them

Comment: This looks really good. However one question: what do you mean by: `if all widgets share a scope, the loading may be triggered in all of them` ? Do you mean like the widgets share the same controller?

Comment: Not exactly, they all can have the same Controller isolated from each other, meaning if i change a scope parameter in one widget it will not reflect the changes in the rest of them

Comment: if thats your case you can add a parameter to app loading like <app-loading widget="1"> and use it to define the widget, so youll need to send parameters in the scope broadcast if youre not familliar with the procedure tell me so i can update my answer :)